# xpath to fetch preliminary nodes only

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml structure:

```html
<pages>

    <author>Me</author>
    <copyright>me inc. 2015,</copyright>
    <lastUpdate>2/1/1999</lastUpdate>

    <Home>--------------------</Home>
    <About>--------------------</About>
    <Contact>------------------</Contact>

</pages>
```

I need an xpath expression that will select all nodes
in pages before Home without having to mention their
tag names. say:

```html
/pages/author/copyright/lastUpdate.
```

the 
expression should say :

select all pages nodes before Home or, select all 
preliminary nodes before Home.

any guide will be appreciated.

Comment: Use backtick to escape XML tags, otherwise the tags won't be visible

Comment: Did it, but only the copyright child was returned. whats wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preceding-sibling` axis for this purpose :

```
/pages/Home/preceding-sibling::*
```

> the preceding-sibling axis contains all the preceding siblings of the context node; if the context node is an attribute node or namespace node, the preceding-sibling axis is empty. [[XPath 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)]

Comment: @OsagieOdigie: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.